# What are the minimum desired capabilities required for iOS device for Mobile Web?

Tags: android, ios, macos, appium, webautomation

I am running appium on MAC machine, working on both android and iOS as well. I defined the desired capabilities for android are working fine and able to launch website. But when I tried with the same desired capabilities for iPhone, it shows me

```
 "[POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"platform":"MAC","platformVersion":"9.1","platformName":"iOS","deviceName":"iPhone 6 Plus","browserName":"Chrome","version":""}}]
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 14.772 ms - 564 
TypeError: Cannot set property 'onResetTimeout' of null"
```

Desired capabilities that I declared are:

```
as:DeviceCapabilities [{platform=MAC, platformVersion=9.1, deviceName=iPhone 6 Plus, browserName=Chrome, version=}]
```

I already updated the Xcode for it but nothing seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The capabilities set by you needs a change from 
`platform=MAC` to `platform=iOS` and `browserName=Chrome` is not a necessity and the `version` seems void in your code.

A corresponding Java code for min desired capabilities (i've tried to quote your details in the example) are :

```
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "9.1");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.IOS);
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone 6 Plus");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP,<app path>);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DesiredCapabilities IOSCapability=new DesiredCapabilities();
IOSCapability.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
IOSCapability.setCapability("platformVersion", OSVERSION);
IOSCapability.setCapability("deviceName", DEVICENAME);
IOSCapability.setCapability("app", APPPATH);
//if you are using real device
IOSCapability.setCapability("udid", UDID);
```